# Toggle Sidebar Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this example I can toggle sidebar only in small screens. But I want to enable this toggle option in all sort of screens. 
I removed visible options `class="visible-xs"` So that I can see the button always. Although it enables me to see the button in all screens, still toggle option only works in small screens. http://www.bootply.com/L1awjlqgab#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your CSS media query accordingly to your desired width.

You can give it for example `9000px`, this should cover almost all device widths.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 9000px) {
```

And yes, if you do so, you need to get rid of the `class="visible-xs"` class.

See your updated bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/9CgQZ3in9S)